# SSH: Only allow known IPs

Tags: ssh

I want to  allow only a known IP address block to SSH into our servers.  I have Windows Server 2012, R2, CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 12 and 14.

What is the best practice for each OS to accomplish this?

Comment: maybe this cabn be done within ssh in which case you should state what ssh server you installed.

Comment: c'mon, this sounds like we should do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you could accomplish this, however I'll tell you what I do for my clients.

Depending on the way you want to accomplish this (I use VLANs/subnets,ACLs,and security groups), I typically make a network security group (usually on the firewall/switch/router that I'm working with) that consists of either the IP range, server group, or network objects that I'll be allowing access for, and then I use ACLs to restrict the traffic.

For example, let's say that you are allowing these servers that you've mentioned above to connect through SSH (TCP port 22) to your servers on an internal/external basis; meaning the servers you mentioned above are external, or outside of your LAN and that the servers you're allowing them to SSH into ARE on your LAN.  You would create a group of objects on your firewall and call it External SSH Clients and put all of the external/public IPs of these servers into this group.  Then, you'd make another group on the firewall for the servers residing on your internal LAN that they could access and call it something like Internal Servers SSH Allowed.  Next, you'd make an ACL that would allow traffic from the external clients to the internal servers.  So for instance, your ACL would look something like this:

Source:  External SSH Clients

Destination:  Internal Servers SSH Allowed

Protocol/Port:  SSH/22

Allow/Deny:  Allow

If this was a firewall or some device like that you'd put this rule some where above your implicit deny rule (a rule to implicitly deny all traffic unless explicitly allowed), which is usually the last rule of an ACL, so that it would take effect before any denies.

This scenario only accounts for coming from a public set of IPs or clients outside of your network to an internal group of servers on your local network over SSH.  There are many other ways to accomplish this, and other scenarios; perhaps you're wondering how to do this internally where all servers are local, or on your LAN, and in that case it's really not much different.  I just tried to give you the basic mindset of how you'd accomplish this.  Let me know if anything doesn't make sense and I can clarify more with details.

Comment: Also, I can give you specific examples for specific models of firewalls I've worked with if you have a particular vendor in mind, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my /etc/hosts.allow:
sshd: 198.xxx.xxx.xxx/255.255.255.248
sshd: 192.168.x.0/255.255.255.0

and /etc/hosts.deny:
sshd: ALL

And restarted SSH.  Seems to be working.